# In Outlook 2010 VSTO, how to hide builtin Groups?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am trying to hide Built-In Groups (GroupContactsNew) in TabContacts. I have tried below CustomUI but "getTabContactGroupEnabled" never fires.

Does anyone knows how to do this? BTW: I was able to make entire "TabContacts" tab invisible by registering "getVisible" callback method at tab level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">


<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabContacts">  
<group idMso="GroupContactsNew" getEnabled="getTabContactGroupEnabled">
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Ramesh,

You need to rebuild the UI from scratch setting the **startFromScratch** attribute to true and defining tabs, groups and controls anew, declaring them with the idMso values. In that case you will be able to handle callbacks of the built-in controls.

Read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: One thing forgotten to mention, my Add-in is developed using Outlook 2010. I already have ribbon define. Sample is given earlier. when I add callback function for idMso at group level it doesn't work.
Do you have any working sample for Outlook 2010 add-in?

Comment: You need to have the startFromScratch attribute set to true to get it working.

Comment: I did that as well. any suggestions what is wrong in below ribbon XML?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabContacts">  
 <group idMso="GroupContactsNew" getEnabled="getTabContactButtonEnabled">
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>

  </ribbon>
</customUI>

Comment: You need to use the **getVisible** callback instead.